# windows 7 home upgrade to windows 7 pro and legacy system

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

I got windows 7 home,
and i need to upgrade the system to windows 7 pro. 
this is a legacy system that needs to stay windows 7, and i need to enhance it to windows 7 pro to support feature that are only on windows 7 pro.

I tried looking to buy a liences for windows 7 pro upgrade, but all retailers say they have only windows 8 upgrade.

I addressed microsoft and there representative answered, "we dont sell windows 7 , its off the shelf".

Trying the upgrade within the windows, shows that it is not available in my country.

Do you know where can i BUY a "windows 7 home upgrade to windows 7 pro"?

Comment: Amazon still sells `Windows 7 Professional` on their website.

Comment: yea, list price 85$ , amazon sellers 285$ http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B002JYU5WI/ref=dp_olp_0?ie=UTF8&condition=all, not including shipping and custom taxes.

Comment: I never claimed it would be cheap.  Besides `Windows 7 Professional` was sold NEW by Microsoft for around that price.  You can always purchase it from Amazon directly http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-FQC-00129-Windows-7-Professional/dp/B002DHLVII/ref=sr_1_3?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1363179740&sr=1-3&keywords=windows+7+professional+64+bit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "Windows Anytime Upgrade". Running it from Control panel and gives me the option to update to Ultimate from Professional.

Other than that, Windows 8 Pro System Builder does include downgrade rights. You will need a Windows 7 Pro media and a Key, even one that has been activated before. When activating the machine, you need to contact Microsoft and provide them with the Windows 8 Pro details.

References:

- [Downgrade rights details and FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en-gb/licensing/sblicensing/pages/what_to_do_downgrade_rights.aspx#fbid=Rx6OS_95giw)
- [Downgrade Your New Windows 8 Computer to Windows 7 for Free](http://lifehacker.com/5974318/downgrade-your-new-windows-8-computer-to-windows-7-for-free)

Comment: i don't have a valid disk of windows 7 pro. and it seams that my country is not part of the world that can do "windows Anytime upgrade".