# Windows 7 how to upgrade version without full reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

Is it possible to upgrade from home basic to ultimate without doing a clean install? Is it as simple as putting an Ultimate dvd in the drive and starting an upgrade install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [windows 7 home upgrade to windows 7 pro and legacy system](http://superuser.com/questions/565220/windows-7-home-upgrade-to-windows-7-pro-and-legacy-system)

Answer (score 4):

Try "Windows Anytime Upgrade". Which should be under All Programs in the start menu.

[image]

Comment: Bah, you beat be by about 30 Sec, teaches me to do two screenshots instead of one :)

Comment: Just to elaborate, you don't even need the DVD to do this, windows just "turns on" the ultimate features that are turned off in basic. Also you don't have to go to ultimate, [Home Basic can do a anytime upgrade to Home Premium, Professional, or Ultimate](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok but I have bought an upgrade dvd of ultimate, how to upgrade that way?

Comment: Enter the key in Windows Anytime Upgrade, it accepts full or upgrade keys in addition to keys from Windows Anytime Upgrade SKUs. One exception is if the current install uses a Windows 7 Professional volume license then you can't use Windows Anytime Upgrade to go to Ultimate.

Comment: ok, but is it possible to upgrade without using the Anytime Upgrade?

Comment: Just stumbled on this.  Yes it is possible.  If you get any errors though, simply reboot the computer.  Apparently this is a common workaround and I've just upgraded from Pro to Ultimate using the Ultimate license key (I did get a key error but just rebooted). http://bit.ly/19z8nnk